# Delay in keyboard key strokes if touchpad is touched

Tags: keyboard, touchpad, synaptics

I have an Acer laptop with ElanTech touchpad and Ubuntu 18.04. Everytime I accidentally touch the touchpad while typing, the keystrokes get queued and delayed. This is especially noticeable in gaming, where if my palm accidentally touches the touchpad, I experience a delay before the keystroke actions get executed. This issue persists even with syndaemon running or even if I disable the touchpad entirely with xinput. What could be the issue that is causing this and how can it be solved?